# Check if one collection of values contains another

Tags: c#

Suppose I have two collections as follows:

Collection1:
"A1"
"A1"
"M1"
"M2"

Collection2:
"M2"
"M3"
"M1"
"A1"
"A1"
"A2"

all the values are string values. I want to know if all the elements in Collection1 are contained in Collection2, but I have no guarantee on the order and a set may have multiple entries with the same value. In this case, Collection2 does contain Collection1 because Collection2 has two A1's, M1 and M2. Theres the obvious way: sorting both collections and popping off values as i find matches, but I was wondering if there's a faster more efficient way to do this. Again with the initial collections I have no guarantee on the order or how many times a given value will appear

EDIT: Changed set to collection just to clear up that these aren't sets as they can contain duplicate values

Comment: Total guess out of the blue, is this homework (or possibly an interview question)?

Comment: Nah, I'm writing some logic for a game, and I want to add a feature where a bunch of actions/attacks can be stacked together then reduced into different one

Comment: @user127817: Haha okay, sorry! We ask that question here a lot (to prevent giving out the direct answer to a homework problem), and I would imagine it gets pretty annoying to the users who *aren't* asking about homework. Interesting question! :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, there is a faster way, provided you're not space-constrained. (See [space/time tradeoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-time_tradeoff).)

The algorithm:

Just insert all the elements in Set2 into a hashtable (in C# 3.5, that's a [HashSet<string>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx)), and then go through all the elements of Set1 and check if they're in the hashtable. This method is faster (Θ(m + n) time complexity), but uses O(n) space.

Alternatively, just say:

```
bool isSuperset = new HashSet<string>(set2).IsSupersetOf(set1);
```

---

**Edit 1:**

For those people concerned about the possibility of duplicates (and hence the misnomer "set"), the idea can easily be extended:

Just make a new `Dictionary<string, int>` representing the count of each word in the super-list (add one to the count each time you see an instance of an existing word, and add the word with a count of 1 if it's not in the dictionary), and then go through the sub-list and decrement the count each time. If every word exists in the dictionary *and* the count is never zero when you try to decrement it, then the subset is in fact a sub-list; otherwise, you had too many instances of a word (or it didn't exist at all), so it's not a real sub-list.

---

**Edit 2:**

If the strings are very big and you're concerned about space efficiency, and an algorithm that works with (very) high probability works for you, then try storing a *hash* of each string instead. It's technically not *guaranteed* to work, but the probability of it not working is pretty darn low.

Comment: Just use [`IsSubsetOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358446.aspx) :)

Comment: @Porges: Edit: I thought you meant that `IsSubsetOf` is a LINQ method, but it wasn't -- is that method really what you meant, or did you mean `IsSupersetOf`? (I think using `IsSubsetOf` on the subset is slower than using `IsSupersetOf` on the superset.)

Comment: If you have duplicates, using sets and set theory is not the way to go. "A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements" and the logic makes this assumption. If you remove the second A1 from Set2, both A1s from Set1 will still be considered as "in" Set2.

Comment: I have an alternative. Whether it is better or not is to be determined, but the point about set theory remains.

Comment: @druttka: Yeah I commented on your post, see my comment. :)

Comment: @user127817: Sure. Be careful about case sensitivity!

Comment: I implemented it using hashsets and the dictionary, and I'm amazed how fast this is. With a stack of 6 objects int he first collection and 25000 collection to compare against, it takes ~5 milliseconds.

Thanks alot :)

Comment: @user127817: Glad it helped! This is where knowledge of data structures and algorithms comes handy (especially hashtables) -- if you're not too familiar with them, I highly recommend reading about them. [This book](https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms.html) explains things amazingly well, although it might be going a little too deep. On the other hand, browsing around good ol' [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtable) can also teach a lot as well. :)

Answer (score 47):

The most concise way I know of:

```
//determine if Set2 contains all of the elements in Set1
bool containsAll = Set1.All(s => Set2.Contains(s));
```

Comment: Clearly the best answer.  Not sure how it measures on perf. but in my situation, this is perfect.

Comment: If you want to determine if Set1 and Set2 contain the same elements irrespective of order you can do:
if (Set1.All(s => Set2.Contains(s)) && Set2.All(s => Set1.Contains(s))) { ... }

Comment: Great solution!. In case you need to know what are the common objects between collections you can use:
a.Intersect(b) where a and b are the collection.

Comment: or `Set1.All(Set2.Contains)`

Answer (score 5):

The problem I see with the HashSet, Intersect, and other Set theory answers is that you do contain duplicates, and "A set is a collection that contains no duplicate elements". Here's a way to handle the duplicate cases.

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "A1", "A1", "M1", "M2" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "M2", "M3", "M1", "A1", "A1", "A2" };

// Remove returns true if it was able to remove it, and it won't be there to be matched again if there's a duplicate in list1
bool areAllPresent = list1.All(i => list2.Remove(i));
```

**EDIT**: I renamed from Set1 and Set2 to list1 and list2 to appease Mehrdad.

**EDIT 2**: The comment implies it, but I wanted to explicitly state that this does alter list2. Only do it this way if you're using it as a comparison or control but don't need the contents afterwards.

Comment: @druttka: +1 for calling them `Set1` and `Set2`, even though you argued against that... it's amusing. :P
And this is insanely slow.

Comment: @Mehrdad I used the names from his example. "Insanely" seems like a relative term, and at least it works unlike the set theory solutions posted elsewhere.

Comment: @druttka: It's not relative, since this is O(m * n) while the other solution is O(m + n). Whether it's a misnomer or another issue is a different issue, but this solution is a pretty slow one IMHO. :(

Comment: @Mehrdad your option will fail if he removes one instance of A1 from Set2 in his example data. This option works. Sometimes you have to do more processing to get the right answer. If you can improve your answer to return false when Set2 only includes one instance of "A1", I'll vote you up.

Comment: @druttka: I extended my answer; hopefully that's better? :]

Comment: I was surprised that you did not include the performance calculations of your additional loop and increment/decrement operations :p I'll vote it up since the Dictionary approach is a workable alternative.

Comment: @druttka: Haha thanks for the upvote. :) Hm... where's the additional loop? I'm only looping once for adding/incrementing, then once for removing/decrementing -- nothing more than before, just an extra `if` inside each loop. It should still be O(m + n)...

Answer (score 4):

Check out [linq.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#except2)..

```
string[] set1 = {"A1", "A1", "M1", "M2" };
string[]  set2 = { "M2", "M3", "M1", "A1", "A1", "A2" };

var matching = set1.Intersect(set2);

foreach (string x in matching)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: I've found LINQ to be slow in practice, even though the theoretical time complexity is still optimal. :\  (The iterators are a big bottleneck sometimes.)

Comment: This doesn't solve the OP's problem - the problem is "does collection2 contain all elements of collection1, taking into account duplicates. Intersect() just returns ONE of every string in set1 that is in set2. i.e. {"A1", "M1", "M2"}

Comment: Should be collection *subtraction*, not *intersection*.

Answer (score 0):

Similar one

```
string[] set1 = new string[] { "a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","aa","ab" };
string[] set2 = new string[] {"m1","m2","a4","a6","a1" };

var a = set1.Select(set => set2.Contains(set));
```

Comment: since it's not obvious what the return values are, you should be explicit with your typing.  What is 'a'?

Comment: It returns the List (or Collection or whatever you may want to call it) of all elements of set1 that are inside set2. Consequently, it does not correctly check if set2 contains ALL elements of set1, because as long as set2 contains 1 element of set1, `Any()` will always be true.