# C# Performance and best practice to check the state of a bit Array

Tags: c#, algorithm

Here's my problem:

- I have two classes: `ClassObj` and `ClassProperty`;
- One of the properties of `ClassObj` (let's call it `lstProperty`) is a `List` of `ClassProperty` (representing the property that current instance of the object have);
- At runtime I have stored somewhere an `Array` of all possible `ClassProperty`, we will call this `Array` `arrPossibleProperty`.

My issue is to find a REALLY fast way of checking if an instance of `ClassObj` match a particular set of `ClassProperty` (if he have in his `lstProperty` all the `ClassProperty` of a given set).

I was thinking about creating an `array` of `Bit` representing the sequence of `ClassProperty` that the `ClassObj` posesses. Using as reference the `Array` `arrPossibleProperty`, and the index of his `Property`.

So if for example we have 10 property and a `InstanceA` of `ClassObj` have the 1st the 4th and the 9th I would generate this array of bit:
1001000010

My question is, **how can I check for example (Fastest and Most performing solution) that the array of bit have (for example) the 3rd and the 4th Property?**

Of course if you need there's a more performing way of doing this let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use bitwise-operations, such as `&`, `|`, `^` or `~` (depending on your needs)

Taking your example of 1001000010, to find out if the 3rd bit is set, you'd want to do this: `1001000010 & 0000000100 != 0000000000`, or rather

```
bool isSet = myProperty & (1 << (option - 1)) != 0; // to find out if `myProperty` has the property `option` set.
myProperty |= 1 << (option -  1); // to set property `option`
```

For more information about bitwise operations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

**Alternatively** and a lot more easy to implement, would be using enums.

```
[Flags]
enum ClassProperty
{
    None = 0x00,
    First = 0x01,
    Second = 0x02,
    Third = 0x04,
    Fourth = 0x08
    // add more if needed
}
```

Then, you'd use the enum like this

```
myProperty = ClassProperty.First | ClassProperty.Second; // sets both First and Second
bool thirdIsSet = myProperty.HasFlag(ClassProperty.Third);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll try both implementation to see which will be the most performing. Really thank you!

Comment: Note that you can check multiple flags simultaneously, e.g. myProperty.HasFlag(ClassProperty.Third | ClassProperty.Fourth). However, using HasFlag is likely to be thousands of times slower than using bitflags. (Although we're comparing milliseconds with nanoseconds ;)

Answer (score 1):

You say your array of all possible ClassProperty-objects (`arrPossibleProperty`) are initalized at run-time. I then assume you don't know how large that array might be. That rules out Enums, which by definition are hard coded. If you instead go for some sort of bitmap as you indicate in your question, you need at some point to iterate arrPossibleProperty *and* your list of ClassProperty `lstProperty` in order to do the mapping and unmapping.

My point is you are making a lot of assumptions claiming that doing this bit-fiddling is faster, while you're actually working with high-level C# objects. Never assume. Test. Measure.

Here is a [question quite similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162810/c-sharp-check-if-one-collection-of-values-contains-another), in which the answer uses standard .NET library functions to do what you want:

```
HashSet<T>().IsSupertSetOf().
```

Is it fast *enough*? Then use it instead of creating far more unreadable code with bit-operations.